# Copy from sheet before active worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

May I know is there any vba code to copy from previous worksheet(sheet before current worksheet)  to the active worksheet?

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
Public Sub CpySheet()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim name As String
    name = ActiveSheet.name
    i = ActiveSheet.Index

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets(i).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Worksheets(i - 1).Copy after:=Worksheets(i - 1)
    Sheets(i).name = name
End Sub
```